# Getting Windows Accounts Chrome plugin working with Electron

Tags: plugins, electron, single-sign-on, chromium, windows-authentication

To authenticate devices (PC's) towards Microsoft systems (MSAL) in Chrome, the plugin "[Windows Accounts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-accounts/ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji)" is required.

However, I can't get it to work. When accessing our websites from either an Edge browser or a Chrome browser with said plugin, the sytems receives DeviceID upon logon. Through Electron with plugin installed, nohting.

It might be that this plugin is not compatible with the version of Chromium present in Electron v24. Could be that it requires a special process to install this plugin within Electron.

I expect that the DeviceID is sent to Microsoft during authentication, to verify that this is an approved device. Then MFA would not be triggered. However, MFA is triggered and logs show no DeviceID is being sent.

Tried with Edge - works
Tried with Chrome + plugin - works
Installed plugin in Electron - nothin

Comment: I have the same issue... only thing I can add is that I tried the extension in the Chromium browser and it doesn't work. Plugin doesn't seem to do anything.